# Input Fields Not Displaying Data in Microsoft Edge

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, microsoft-edge

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application using Razor. When it loads, it displays saved data in input fields. This works fine in IE 11, but when viewing in Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.51, the values are not being displayed.

When I view the source I see the value is set, but am not sure why it's not displaying in Edge. Has anyone been experiencing this?

```
<input class="small-input form-control text-right" data-val="true" data-val-regex="The field must match the regular expression &#39;^[-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)[%]?$&#39;." data-val-regex-pattern="^[-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)[%]?$" id="SignificantActivityInputs" name="SignificantActivityInputs" type="number" value="10%" />
```

There are other fields that are displaying the text. The difference I can see with them are:

1. They have an associated field that is of type "hidden"
2. The "main" field is of type "text" where the ones that aren't displaying are of type "number" as shown above.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: The issue can't be reproduced with only one line of code. Number type should also work. You can add breakpoints in your code to check the data returned from the backend and check if there're any other issues in your code. If you decide to take Chris Wong's advice to change number type to text, you can mark his answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: That is the rendered HTML. The actual code is as follows: 
 `@Html.TextBoxFor( m=>m.SignificantActivityInputs.Management.Weighting, new { @class = "small-input form-control text-right", @type = "number" })`  where `Weighting`  is being returned as a string. As I mentioned in my comment, the percentages are now appearing but I need to test to ensure that it doesn't affect anything downstream. There are calculations done on these values. Once confirmed successful I will mark it as an accepted answer. Wouldn't want to mislead anyone by marking the answer 'accepted' only to find issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `type` should be `text`, instead of `number`

```
<input class="small-input form-control text-right" 
                data-val="true" 
                data-val-regex="The field must match the regular expression &#39;^[-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)[%]?$&#39;." 
                data-val-regex-pattern="^[-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)[%]?$" 
                id="SignificantActivityInputs" 
                name="SignificantActivityInputs" 
                type="text" 
                value="10%" />
```

Comment: That is the obvious culprit, but number is a valid type for the HTML input tag, so shouldn't this continue to work in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: I updated the code from `@Html.TextBoxFor( m=>m.ActivityInputs.Management.Weighting, new { @class = "small-input form-control text-right", @type = "number" })` to `@Html.TextBoxFor( m=>m.ActivityInputs.Management.Weighting, new { @class = "small-input form-control text-right", @type = "text" })` and the values are now showing. I just need to test to ensure that this doesn't affect anything downstream.